# What do the symbols (icons) in the Borderlands multiplayer game info mean?

Tags: borderlands

When looking for an online game to join on Borderlands (I have the PS3 version), sometimes there are little icons or symbols in the information for a particular game, under the words "Plot Mission :" and the name of the mission. For example, one looks like a little box with a parachute. (I can't make out what the rest are.) What do these symbols indicate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am going to assume you mean these:

[image]

That is the DLC indicator. The symbols are General Knoxx, Moxxi's Underdome, and Island of Dr. Ned, from left to right. If there is a checkmark by it like so, it means that the host has the DLC.

If you see a black X in a red circle next to the image, like this,

[image]

then the host does not have that particular piece of DLC. You can see in this particular example that the host has none of the DLC at all.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks!